# How to read .rda file as dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, rda

I have a `.rda` file and i want to read it in `R` and aim to convert it to `dataframe` and eventually i have to read it as `.maf` filer in `maftools` but i am failing on first step.
By doing

```
File<-load(file.choose()) #loading .rda file
head(File)
Name
```

How to read it.

Comment: `.rda` suggests `save` was used, and using `\`<-\`()` on `load` won't work . Better use `saveRDS` for a single object, then it's `File <- readRDS()` which gives you back a data.frame if it was saved as such.

Answer (score 1):

`load()` doesn't return a value, it populates an environment (with one or several objects), by default the local one but this can be tweaked, maybe this will be useful:

```r
my_obj <- 42
save(my_obj, file = "foo.rda")
rm(my_obj)

e <- new.env()
load("foo.rda", envir = e)
e$my_obj
#> [1] 42
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>